# How to find implication classes in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, equivalence-relations

I understood the general idea of comparability graphs and transitive orientation but just can't wrap my head around the implication classes.
From Advanced Topics in Graph Algorithms - Ron Shamir.
[image]

**How exactly these implication classes are constructed ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the definition, we can build the following table for which edges *directly force* which other edges in Figure 6.5:

\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
  \Gamma & ab & ac & ad & ae & bc & bd & be & cd \\
\hline
   ab & & \\
   ac & & & & \times \\
   ad & & & & \times \\
   ae & & \times & \times \\
   bc & & & & & & & \times \\
   bd & & & & & & & \times \\
   be & & & & & \times & \times \\
   cd \\
\end{array}
Taking the reflexive-transitive closure of this relation gives us the following:

\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
  \Gamma^* & ab & ac & ad & ae & bc & bd & be & cd \\
\hline
   ab &\times & \\
   ac & & \times & \times &\times \\
   ad & & \times & \times &\times \\
   ae & & \times & \times &\times \\
   bc & & & & & \times & \times & \times \\
   bd & & & & & \times & \times & \times \\
   be & & & & & \times & \times & \times \\
   cd & & & & & & & & \times \\
\end{array}

The equivalence classes of $\Gamma^*$ are therefore $\{ab\}$, $\{ac, ad, ae\}$, $\{bc,bd,be\}$, and $\{cd\}$.

Comment: Thanks ! this makes it much clear